# Autostart Neo4j database?

Tags: database, neo4j, autostart

I want to autostart a Neo4j database every time I login to Windows. I can put the shortcut of `Neo4j Desktop.exe` in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Neo4j Desktop` in `shell:startup`, but that only starts the Neo4j Desktop interface. I want it to autoclick the start button and have Neo4j Browser be ready as well. I suppose AutoHotKey can does this, but I don't think it's a clever way to do so.

[image]

Comment: Would the following work? Install Neo4j as a Windows service https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/#windows-service and configure to automatically start?

Comment: How to install the service with `bin\neo4j install-service`? Where is `bin`?

Comment: If you scroll up a bit in the page I linked you to, you'll find the archive to download and install. The installed files will contain a bin folder. Then, you'll be able to auto-start the server and access localhost:7474 to access Neo4j browser.

Comment: Ah I see. Hmm, I wonder why does the Neo4j Desktop not include the [Community Server](https://neo4j.com/download-center/#community "Neo4j Download Center - Neo4j Graph Database Platform")? Apparently I can still open localhost:7474, so it should be installed somewhere