# Neo4j Desktop is running, but `neo4j status` still says that the server is not running?

Tags: server, service, neo4j

In my understanding, opening Neo4j Desktop is [equivalent](https://neo4j.com/download-center/#desktop) to starting a server. However, when I check this with [`invoke-neo4j status`](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/#powershell-examples) it says Neo4j is not running. Do you know why is that?

This is the verbose output:

```
PS D:\Downloads\neo4j-community-4.3.5-windows\neo4j-community-4.3.5\bin> invoke-neo4j status -verbose
VERBOSE: Server command specified
VERBOSE: Java detected at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe'
VERBOSE: Invoking "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe" -version 2>&1
VERBOSE: Command returned with exit code 0
VERBOSE: Java version response: openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
VERBOSE: Java Version detected as 11
VERBOSE: Starting neo4j utility using command line C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe -cp
"D:\Downloads\neo4j-community-4.3.5-windows\neo4j-community-4.3.5/lib/*"
-Dbasedir="D:\Downloads\neo4j-community-4.3.5-windows\neo4j-community-4.3.5" org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jCommand
"status"
Neo4j is not running.
3
```

My goal is to [autostart a database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69403002/3416774) and use Cypher in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening Neo4j Desktop is NOT equivalent to starting a server. You simply open a user interface and it requires an active connection to a running neo4j database.

For an analogy, if you open ithe door of your car and sit on the driver seat you still need to start your engine so that it will move.

Comment: I have [a couple more questions](https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo4j-desktop-is-running-but-neo4j-status-still-says-that-the-server-is-not-running/45443/5) regarding Neo4j server and service. Can you take a look at it? Many thanks